# Status of the TMS specifications

Tags: tile-map-service

I am trying to implement some TMS specs as per http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification. I am particularly interested in the service discovery part ( and ).

The page is very clear wrt status of the specs, ie experimental. I am wondering if it is worth implementing it at all in fact.

Bottom line is that I am struggling to find a server that would actually comply to the specs above mentioned.

Does anyone know of such a server? + state of the specs? should I just stick to the good old url pattern and drop all the server service discovery stuff?

Thanks for any pointers,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GeoWebCache docs](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/tms.html) it seems that it has been superseded by [WMTS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts) but that GeoWebCache (i.e. most GeoServers) should be able to handle a request for TMS tiles.

That said I've never tried it my self.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the link. I guess there won't be much progress on TMS specs in the future. I will just stick to the basics then (url pattern) and forget about the service capabilities. I have a few links to TMS services (such as the great ESRI one at http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/) but I have not found a TMS (meta) directory yet. Any idea?